# Mathematica 13 not working in Windows Virtual Desktop ("requires Desktop Experience")

Tags: installation

Anyone know how to get Mathematica 13 working in Windows Virtual Desktop?  I get "This application requires the Desktop Experience for Windows Server to be installed."  It's certainly not a server without a graphic interface.

EDIT:  On the phone they said to install 13.0 or 13.01 as a workaround.

Comment: I think Wolfram Tech support is a better place for this question.